# C puzzle {MACRO}

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I came across the following puzzle somewhere

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    {

        /*Fill in something here to make this code compile  
           ........... 
         */   
        ooOoO+=a;    
    } 
    #undef ooOoO 
    printf("%d",ooOoO); 

    return 0;
}
```

In short I want to ask how can I use `ooOoO` in printf after it has been `#undef` ed?

Comment: You have two opening braces after `main()`; is that intended?

Comment: I think it is. That one makes the puzzle even interesting.

Comment: @James It's intended, and prevents trivial solutions like that of VJo below.

Comment: @Jim:  Since a block can be empty, it doesn't really add anything to the problem:  any solution would just need to start with a closing brace.

Comment: @James Thanks, you're right, adding a } to VJo's "trivial" solution would be a "trivial" modification. Sorry for the brainfart.

Answer (score 11):

You need to declare it as a variable:

```
#define ooOoO int ooOoO = 42; int a = 1; { ooOoO
```

Macro-replacement is non-recursive; while `ooOoO` is being replaced, the identifier `ooOoO` will not be treated as a macro name.

---

If you are looking for a solution that does *not* use a macro, then you can simply ignore the `#undef` directive and never declare `ooOoO` as a macro.  It is permitted in both C and C++ to `#undef` an identifier that is not defined as a macro.

Comment: why the opening bracket? There number of opening brackets in the OPs question matches the number of closing brackets. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Atmoscreations:  I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the second left brace following `main()` was a typo; if it isn't, then the block it introduces would need to be closed anyway before declaring `ooOoO` as a variable, otherwise it would not be in scope when the `printf` statement is reached.

Comment: I think the bracket is intended... But you're right. This causes the variable to be out of scope otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

After reformatting the code (indent) and adding the solution, that's what I receive:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    {
/*-Insert starts here-*/
    }
    int ooOoO = 0, a=3;
    {
/*-Insert ends here-*/
        ooOoO+=a;      
    }       
    #undef ooOoO 
    printf("%d",ooOoO);       
    return 0;
}
```

compiles and prints `3`

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int ooOoO = 0;
    {
        int a = 3;
        ooOoO+=a;
    }
    #undef ooOoO
    printf("%d",ooOoO);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the second opening bracket is missing after main. doesn't match the question though

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
{

      /*Fill in something here to make this code compile  

*/
}
int a = 0, ooOoO=0;
#define ooOoO ooOoO
{
/*
      */   
              ooOoO+=a;    
          } 
          #undef ooOoO 
          printf("%d",ooOoO); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you seem to miss that there's a `}` missing at the end and therefore doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The #undef undefines the symbol to the preprocessor so that it does not get substituted with something else, but ooOoO still gets to the compiler.

Comment: Of course, but how did ooOoO get defined within scope? That's what the other answers provide.

Comment: Sure, but this was explicitly asked. James McNeils gave the solution but only explained this in an edit after I posted (and I cannot comment yet).